# Problem installing Laravel on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, helpfile, project-management

I am a Ubuntu newbie. While installing Laravel using terminal, I came across this issue:

```
roger@roger-P580:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ cd /var/www/laravel    

roger@roger-P580:/var/www/laravel$ a2ensite laravel.example.com    

ERROR: Site laravel.example.com does not exist!
```

What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

You asked "problem installing laravel", in that case simply do steps 1 to 3 correctly from this guide : [Refer to this working guide to install laravel,](http://tecadmin.net/install-laravel-framework-on-ubuntu/#)

Otherwise if those steps are clear, you might refer the last steps-
Assuming you created a virtual host, you have to reload the service :

`$ a2ensite laravel.example.com`

`$ sudo service apache2 reload`

And after that put up a port for accesing it thru browser.

`sudo echo "127.0.0.1  laravel.example.com" >> /etc/hosts`